# Determine contiguous date intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following table structure:

```
id int -- more like a group id, not unique in the table
AddedOn datetime -- when the record was added
```

For a specific `id` there is **at most** one record each day. I have to write a query that returns contiguous (at day level) date intervals for each `id`.
The expected result structure is:

```
id int
StartDate datetime
EndDate datetime
```

Note that the time part of `AddedOn` is available but it is not important here.

To make it clearer, here is some input data:

```
with data as 
(
  select * from
  (
    values
    (0, getdate()), --dummy record used to infer column types

    (1, '20150101'),
    (1, '20150102'),
    (1, '20150104'),
    (1, '20150105'),
    (1, '20150106'),

    (2, '20150101'),
    (2, '20150102'),
    (2, '20150103'),
    (2, '20150104'),
    (2, '20150106'),
    (2, '20150107'),

    (3, '20150101'),
    (3, '20150103'),
    (3, '20150105'),
    (3, '20150106'),
    (3, '20150108'),
    (3, '20150109'),
    (3, '20150110')
  ) as d(id, AddedOn)
  where id > 0 -- exclude dummy record
)
select * from data
```

And the expected result:

```
id      StartDate      EndDate
1       2015-01-01     2015-01-02
1       2015-01-04     2015-01-06

2       2015-01-01     2015-01-04
2       2015-01-06     2015-01-07

3       2015-01-01     2015-01-01
3       2015-01-03     2015-01-03
3       2015-01-05     2015-01-06
3       2015-01-08     2015-01-10
```

Although it looks like a common problem I couldn't find a similar enough question. Also I'm getting closer to a solution and I will post it when (and if) it works but I feel that there should be a more elegant one.

Comment: Gaps and Islands: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/ https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175780%28v=sql.80%29.aspx http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samlester/archive/2012/09/04/tsql-solve-it-your-way-gaps-and-islands-with-a-twist.aspx In SQL Server 2012 I'd use `LAG` or `LEAD`, but in 2008 there would be self joins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's answer without any fancy joining, but simply using group by and row_number, which is not only simple but also more efficient.

```
WITH CTE_dayOfYear
AS
(
    SELECT  id,
            AddedOn,
            DATEDIFF(DAY,'20000101',AddedOn) dyID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID,AddedOn) row_num
    FROM data
)

SELECT  ID,
        MIN(AddedOn) StartDate,
        MAX(AddedOn) EndDate,
        dyID-row_num AS groupID
FROM CTE_dayOfYear
GROUP BY ID,dyID - row_num
ORDER BY ID,2,3
```

The logic is that the dyID is based on the date so there are gaps while row_num has no gaps. So every time there is a gap in dyID, then it changes the difference between row_num and dyID. Then I simply use that difference as my groupID.

Comment: All solutions are correct and they get deserved upvote. However, I accept this one as answer because it's compact.

Answer (score 3):

In `Sql Server 2008` it is a little bit pain without `LEAD` and `LAG` functions:

```
WITH    data
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id, AddedOn ) AS rn
               FROM     ( VALUES ( 0, GETDATE()), --dummy record used to infer column types
                        ( 1, '20150101'), ( 1, '20150102'), ( 1, '20150104'),
                        ( 1, '20150105'), ( 1, '20150106'), ( 2, '20150101'),
                        ( 2, '20150102'), ( 2, '20150103'), ( 2, '20150104'),
                        ( 2, '20150106'), ( 2, '20150107'), ( 3, '20150101'),
                        ( 3, '20150103'), ( 3, '20150105'), ( 3, '20150106'),
                        ( 3, '20150108'), ( 3, '20150109'), ( 3, '20150110') )
                        AS d ( id, AddedOn )
               WHERE    id > 0 -- exclude dummy record
             ),
        diff
          AS ( SELECT   d1.* ,
                        CASE WHEN ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd, d2.AddedOn, d1.AddedOn),
                                         1) = 1 THEN 0
                             ELSE 1
                        END AS diff
               FROM     data d1
                        LEFT JOIN data d2 ON d1.id = d2.id
                                             AND d1.rn = d2.rn + 1
             ),
        parts
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ( SELECT    SUM(diff)
                          FROM      diff d2
                          WHERE     d2.rn <= d1.rn
                        ) AS p
               FROM     diff d1
             )
    SELECT  id ,
            MIN(AddedOn) AS StartDate ,
            MAX(AddedOn) AS EndDate
    FROM    parts
    GROUP BY id ,
            p
```

Output:

```
id  StartDate               EndDate
1   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 2015-01-02 00:00:00.000
1   2015-01-04 00:00:00.000 2015-01-06 00:00:00.000
2   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 2015-01-04 00:00:00.000
2   2015-01-06 00:00:00.000 2015-01-07 00:00:00.000
3   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000
3   2015-01-03 00:00:00.000 2015-01-03 00:00:00.000
3   2015-01-05 00:00:00.000 2015-01-06 00:00:00.000
3   2015-01-08 00:00:00.000 2015-01-10 00:00:00.000
```

Walkthrough:

**diff**
This `CTE` returns data:

```
1   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 1   0
1   2015-01-02 00:00:00.000 2   0
1   2015-01-04 00:00:00.000 3   1
1   2015-01-05 00:00:00.000 4   0
1   2015-01-06 00:00:00.000 5   0
```

You are joining same table on itself to get the previous row. Then you calculate difference in days between current row and previous row and if the result is 1 day then pick 0 else pick 1.

**parts**
This `CTE` selects result from previous step and sums up the new column(it is a cumulative sum. sum of all values of new column from starting till current row), so you are getting partitions to group by:

```
1   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 1   0   0
1   2015-01-02 00:00:00.000 2   0   0
1   2015-01-04 00:00:00.000 3   1   1
1   2015-01-05 00:00:00.000 4   0   1
1   2015-01-06 00:00:00.000 5   0   1
2   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 6   0   1
2   2015-01-02 00:00:00.000 7   0   1
2   2015-01-03 00:00:00.000 8   0   1
2   2015-01-04 00:00:00.000 9   0   1
2   2015-01-06 00:00:00.000 10  1   2
2   2015-01-07 00:00:00.000 11  0   2
3   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 12  0   2
3   2015-01-03 00:00:00.000 13  1   3
```

The last step is just a grouping by `ID` and `new column` and picking `min` and `max` values for dates.

Answer (score 2):

I took the "Islands Solution #3 from SQL MVP Deep Dives" solution from https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/ and applied to your test data:

```
with 
data as 
(
    select * from
    (
    values
    (0, getdate()), --dummy record used to infer column types

    (1, '20150101'),
    (1, '20150102'),
    (1, '20150104'),
    (1, '20150105'),
    (1, '20150106'),

    (2, '20150101'),
    (2, '20150102'),
    (2, '20150103'),
    (2, '20150104'),
    (2, '20150106'),
    (2, '20150107'),

    (3, '20150101'),
    (3, '20150103'),
    (3, '20150105'),
    (3, '20150106'),
    (3, '20150108'),
    (3, '20150109'),
    (3, '20150110')
    ) as d(id, AddedOn)
    where id > 0 -- exclude dummy record
)
,CTE_Seq
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID
        ,SeqNo
        ,SeqNo - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SeqNo) AS rn
    FROM
        data
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '20150101', AddedOn) AS SeqNo
        ) AS CA
)
SELECT
    ID
    ,DATEADD(day, MIN(SeqNo), '20150101') AS StartDate
    ,DATEADD(day, MAX(SeqNo), '20150101') AS EndDate
FROM CTE_Seq
GROUP BY ID, rn
ORDER BY ID, StartDate;
```

**Result set**

```
ID  StartDate               EndDate
1   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 2015-01-02 00:00:00.000
1   2015-01-04 00:00:00.000 2015-01-06 00:00:00.000
2   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 2015-01-04 00:00:00.000
2   2015-01-06 00:00:00.000 2015-01-07 00:00:00.000
3   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000
3   2015-01-03 00:00:00.000 2015-01-03 00:00:00.000
3   2015-01-05 00:00:00.000 2015-01-06 00:00:00.000
3   2015-01-08 00:00:00.000 2015-01-10 00:00:00.000
```

I'd recommend you to examine the intermediate results of `CTE_Seq` to understand how it actually works. Just put

```
select * from CTE_Seq
```

instead of the final `SELECT ... GROUP BY ...`. You'll get this result set:

```
ID  SeqNo   rn
1   0   -1
1   1   -1
1   3   0
1   4   0
1   5   0
2   0   -1
2   1   -1
2   2   -1
2   3   -1
2   5   0
2   6   0
3   0   -1
3   2   0
3   4   1
3   5   1
3   7   2
3   8   2
3   9   2
```

Each date is converted into a sequence number by `DATEDIFF(day, '20150101', AddedOn)`. `ROW_NUMBER()` generates a set of sequential numbers without gaps, so when these numbers are subtracted from a sequence with gaps the difference jumps/changes. The difference stays the same until the next gap, so in the final `SELECT` `GROUP BY ID, rn` brings all rows from the same island together.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution that does not use analytics. I tend not to use analytics because I work with many different DBMSs and many don't (yet) have them emplemented and even those who do have different syntaxes. I just have the habit of writing generic code whenever possible.

```
with
Data( ID, AddedOn )as(
  select 1, convert( date, '20150101' ) union all
  select 1, '20150102' union all
  select 1, '20150104' union all
  select 1, '20150105' union all
  select 1, '20150106' union all
  select 2, '20150101' union all
  select 2, '20150102' union all
  select 2, '20150103' union all
  select 2, '20150104' union all
  select 2, '20150106' union all
  select 2, '20150107' union all
  select 3, '20150101' union all
  select 3, '20150103' union all
  select 3, '20150105' union all
  select 3, '20150106' union all
  select 3, '20150108' union all
  select 3, '20150109' union all
  select 3, '20150110'
)
select  d.ID, d.AddedOn StartDate, IsNull( d1.AddedOn, '99991231' ) EndDate
from    Data    d
left join Data  d1
    on  d1.ID   = d.ID
    and d1.AddedOn  =(
        select  Min( AddedOn )
        from    data
        where   ID  = d.ID
        and AddedOn > d.AddedOn );
```

In your situation I assume that ID and AddedOn form a composite PK and so are indexed. Thus, the query will run impressively fast even on very large tables.

Also, I used the outer join because it seemed like the last AddedOn date of each ID should be seen in the StartDate column. Instead of NULL I used a common MaxDate value. The NULL could work just as well as a "this is the latest StartDate row" flag.

Here is the output for ID=1:

```
ID          StartDate  EndDate
----------- ---------- ----------
1           2015-01-01 2015-01-02
1           2015-01-02 2015-01-04
1           2015-01-04 2015-01-05
1           2015-01-05 2015-01-06
1           2015-01-06 9999-12-31
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to post my own solution too because it's yet another approach:

```
with data as 
(
  ...
),
temp as 
(
  select     d.id 
            ,d.AddedOn
            ,dprev.AddedOn as PrevAddedOn
            ,dnext.AddedOn as NextAddedOn
  FROM      data d
            left JOIN
            data dprev on   dprev.id = d.id
                       and  dprev.AddedOn = dateadd(d, -1, d.AddedOn)
            left JOIN
            data dnext on   dnext.id = d.id
                       and  dnext.AddedOn = dateadd(d,  1, d.AddedOn)
),
starts AS
(
  select     id
            ,AddedOn 
  from      temp 
  where     PrevAddedOn is NULL
),
ends as
(
  select     id
            ,AddedOn
  from      temp
  where     NextAddedon is NULL
)
SELECT   s.id as id
        ,s.AddedOn as StartDate
        ,(select min(e.AddedOn) from ends e where e.id = s.id and e.AddedOn >= s.AddedOn) as EndDate
from    starts s
```